# Ограничение доступа по ip на 3 часа

Tags: ip

Привет!
Подскажите как можно открывать доступ к определенной странице сайта, раз в 3 часа по ip?

Answer (score 1):

Записывать в базу запись с определенным IP и указать время доступа `текущее время + 10800`. И в нужном файле проверять, открыт ли доступ данному IP (и больше ли время, которое указано в стобце, чем текущее, если да, то открыть доступ).

Comment: Я новичок в этом деле, можно по подробней, какая база и возможно ли это делать автоматически для всех IP?

Comment: Вы это на сайте хотите реализовать?

Comment: У меня есть сайт, мне нужно чтоб каждый посетитель мог не чаще одного раза в 3 часа видеть содержимое определенной страницы.

Comment: вот эта страница: http://www.taxi-picnic.ru/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Вот хостинг на котором расположен сайт, быть может вы с таким знакомы...  hostiman.ru

Comment: При посещении пользователем определенной статьи добавляйте в базу запись с этим IP, и количеством секунд (в php функция time) + 10800 (3 часа. Т.е. пользователь сможет заново увидеть страницу через 3 часа). Затем если пользователь опять посещает страницу, проверять, есть запись с ограничением и столбец, который содержит в себе время (секунды), и если это время имеет значение больше, чем текущее время, то ограничивать доступ. Реализовывается данная задача с помощью `PHP` и `MySQL`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться...

Comment: Еще не скромный вопрос, В какую базу?!, говорю я новичок и мало что понимаю, по этому спрашиваю... А в ответ слышу, завуалировано, иди туда не знаю куда и делай то не знаю что... Может я не совсем понимаю принцип работы данного сервиса, но мне кажется что если человек задает вопрос, он хочет получить конкретный, развернутый ответ, а не указание пальцем в определенном направлении...

Comment: Я Вам уже всё написал. Реализовывается данная задача с помощью `PHP и MySQL`. Если вы даже не знаете, что это такое, то за Вас никто не будет это решать, поэтому нужно ткнуть Вас носом в тему, которая Вам нужна. Я так и сделал, а Вы начинаете мне высказываться тут.